# Zero dipole moment of p-dinitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, dipole

Why is $\mu=0$ for p-dinitrobenzene ? How can the dipole moments of the two Nitro groups exactly cancel each other ? Shouldn't it have a non-zero, albeit feeble, dipole moment ?

Comment: They exactly cancel each other because they are exactly similar.

Comment: Why would it be non-zero? The molecule is planar and the nitro groups are symmetric.

Comment: @bon So both the N-O bonds in a nitro group are of exactly equal length.

Comment: @Abhirikshma Yes that is correct.

Comment: The nitro groups most probably undergo free rotation and so on average are symmetrically disposed about the molecule, so no dipole. If there was some restricted rotational motion, due to say interaction with adjacent H atoms then the dipole could be very small but still approximate to zero.

Comment: @porphyrin The two nitro groups will statistically rotate at a different frequency. The higher rotational states have different bond angles. Plus the still and rotating nitro group have different interaction with the aromatic ring. Both clearly lead to a small, nonvanishing dipole moment.

Comment: @Karl, I am sure that  both nitro's will have the same average behaviour  over time, this time being no more than a few nanosec, and so they will be equivalent (or interchangeable) in any normal dipole measurement. However, my point was that if there is a potential partly restricting rotation,  then it might be that there is a preference for nitro's to be at some angle with the ring and this may generate a small dipole. I say this only as it is reported below that there is a small dipole and so seek an explanation. I do not find this explanation very convincing, however.

Comment: @porphyrin You mean that the rotational states of the two nitros vary so quickly that it can have no influence? In the liquid, possibly, but think about the gas phase. Also: A dipole that fluctuates very quickly is still not a vdW interaction, which are *very* high frequency. I doubt you can neglect it.

Comment: @Karl, By 'quickly' I mean that both nitros exhibit average values of their motion  because of the relatively long time it takes to make a measurement i.e. >> nanoseconds.  Naturally it is assumed that the vapour or solution is dilute enough so that each p-dinitrobenzene is isolated from others and that any  buffer gas or solvent is inert. I don't see what vdW has to do with it.

Comment: We can measure bulk dielectric properties in the gigahertz range, there's no need to do that in nanoseconds. And put dinitrobenzene in an inert solvent and tell me that it has totally the same induced-dipole-only interaction with it than the solvent molecules with themselves.

Answer (score 7):

[This paper (*J. Sep. Sci.* **2011**, 34, 1489–1502)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jssc.201100091/epdf) lists 1,4-Dinitrobenzene as having a very small dipole moment (0.01 Debye). No error is given on the dipole moments, but they do list compounds with exactly zero dipole moment (naphthalene for example).

Answer (score 1):

Let the two nitro groups have a different rotational excitation against the aryl core, and i'm sure you can construct a small dipole moment. Firstly, higher rotational states have different bond angles.

Or easier to imagine: Let one stand in plane with the aryl ring, and one perpendicular or rotating. Different interaction with the aromatic ring, clearly leads to slightly different electronic structure, ergo: a dipole moment.

The dipole moment should vanish at low temperatures, but i guess the stuff crystallises before.